# Hide class if locally stored?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, local-storage

I have a wordpress site and have a message showing on every page load. When button (.ig_close) is clicked I want the message not to show anymore after page refresh.

```
// html
<div class="icegram action_bar_135">
    <div id="icegram_message_135">
        <div class="ig_content">
            <div id="ig_close_135" class="ig_close">
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="ig_data ig_clear_fix">
                <div class="ig_message">Text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


// js
// click button and store locally
jQuery('.ig_close').click(function(){

        localStorage.setItem('saved', true);
        alert('You saved it!');

});

// if saved locally, hide .icegram
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

     if (localStorage.getItem('saved')) {
        alert('its saved!');
        jQuery('.icegram').hide();
        }

 });
```

It's telling me it's locally stored but wont hide my class, why?

Comment: Please show us the HTML snippet for the message.

Comment: @ZoliSzabo added the html. I've been scrambling with this for 2 days, I don't understand why nothing executes even though 'saved' is stored.

Comment: Can you give us an URL to the website?

Comment: I dont think it's allowed but ok brookfieldplacenewsandevents. c o m

Comment: you are checking localstorage item onload and you have not any call when you do 'onclick' event. I think you need to make function and check in that function for item saved and close message. check this link for example: https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/4142/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `<div class="icegram ...">` does not exist in the moment of `document.ready`. They are inserted into the DOM after that moment.

You could need to check if the `Icegram` plugin offers some JavaScript event you can observe and act on.

**EDIT**

Icegram provides a JS object called `icegram`, which exposes a method `icegram.hide_all_messages()`. I think this method is what you should execute in the right moment.

Also, `icegram.messages` is the array containing all the instances of the visible popups; `icegram.messages[0].hide()` will hide the first popup.

You should check out the `icegram` object in your browser's JS console.

All you need to figure out is ***the right moment when to call*** one of the above methods.

Comment: Oh boy, I think i know what you're saying. The plugin has a cta (view more info) that when clicked does exactly what I want, closes the div and doesn't reappear after refresh. The problem is that event directs to a page. I tried to do that with this...

`code
jQuery('.icegram').on('click', '.ig_close', function(){
jQuery(this).closest('.ig_cta').click();
})`

but it's a no go.